# Why I can apply array subscript access syntax on non array

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In C arrays why is this true? a[5] == 5[a]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Consider the following code able to compile under VC2008.

```
int i = 0;

int *j = 0;
int k = 0;

i[j];    // OK?!?!
i[k];    // Compile Error.
```

I was wondering, what is the meaning of `i[j]` in this content?

Comment: In effect, if not in actual expression a possible duplicate of [In C arrays why is this true? a\[5\] == 5\[a\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i[j]` equals to `j[i]`

Therefore it's doing `*(j + i)` which is actually valid since `j` is a pointer.

This doesn't apply for `k` because it isn't a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

It is one of the shocked but legal feature of C/C++ i[j] form to mark offset relative base address and dereference it. So it is legal.
But i[k] - cannot be dereferenced, that is why it is an error.